# Android DatePickerDialog Theme

Tags: android, xamarin, xamarin.android, android-datepicker

I am using the native DatePickerDialog with this theme `Resource.Style.Theme_AppCompat_Light_Dialog_Alert`
and I am getting this pop-up
[ApiLevel 23 and above](https://i.stack.imgur.com/nkdTp.jpg)
and when I use `AlertDialog.ThemeHoloDark` I get the pop-up like this and it says that it is deprecated.
[below api level 23](https://i.stack.imgur.com/TmLrc.png)
I have to support the api level above 15 but I am not able to use the second theme since its deprecated but it is much more user friendly than the new one, how can i use the old theme in my current solution since using it only shows warning and there is no error on using it accross device. Would I face any concerns if I keep my code using the deprecated theme?

Answer (score -1):

Use this in your code it will work for you

```
  // Launch Date Picker Dialog
            DatePickerDialog dpd = new DatePickerDialog(MainActivity.this,
                    new DatePickerDialog.OnDateSetListener() {
                        final Calendar myCalendar = Calendar.getInstance();
                        @Override
                        public void onDateSet(DatePicker view, int year,
                                              int monthOfYear, int dayOfMonth) {
                            // TODO Auto-generated method stub
                            myCalendar.set(Calendar.YEAR, year);
                            myCalendar.set(Calendar.MONTH, monthOfYear);
                            myCalendar.set(Calendar.DAY_OF_MONTH, dayOfMonth);
                            String myFormat = "yyyy-MM-dd"; //In which you need put here
                            SimpleDateFormat sdf = new SimpleDateFormat(myFormat, Locale.US);

                         //   expiry.setText(sdf.format(myCalendar.getTime()));

                        }
                    }, mYear, mMonth, mDay);
            dpd.getDatePicker().setMinDate(System.currentTimeMillis());
            dpd.show();
```

Comment: this solution is not working for me, I am using Resource.Style.Theme_AppCompat_Light_Dialog_Alert  theme and setting the listener. I am having custom logic on press of positive button.